# Cannot import BACKEND 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer' Django Channels 2.1.2

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I have a `Django` project which has multiple apps and uses `Django Channels 2.1.2` for its WebSockets capabilities (for notifications and chat messages).

When I run `daphne -b 127.0.0.1 -p 8000 myproject.asgi:application`

I get the error

```
'ERROR Exception inside application: Cannot import BACKEND 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer' specified for default`
```

The traceback is below

```
127.0.0.1:59202 - - [25/Apr/2019:10:23:09] "WSDISCONNECT /messages/bob" - -
127.0.0.1:59215 - - [25/Apr/2019:10:23:11] "WSCONNECTING /messages/bob" - -
2019-04-25 10:23:11,952 ERROR    Exception inside application: Cannot import BACKEND 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer' specified for default
  File "/Users/me/myapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 175, in __call__
    return await self.inner(receive, self.send)
  File "/Users/me/myapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/middleware.py", line 41, in coroutine_call
    await inner_instance(receive, send)
  File "/Users/me/myapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 42, in __call__
    self.channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
  File "/Users/me/myapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/layers.py", line 344, in get_channel_layer
    return channel_layers[alias]
  File "/Users/me/myapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/layers.py", line 76, in __getitem__
    self.backends[key] = self.make_backend(key)
  File "/Users/me/myapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/layers.py", line 46, in make_backend
    return self._make_backend(name, config)
  File "/Users/me/myapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/layers.py", line 69, in _make_backend
    "Cannot import BACKEND %r specified for %s" % (self.configs[name]["BACKEND"], name)
  Cannot import BACKEND 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer' specified for default
```

I have a virtual environment activated and everything is properly installed.

settings.py (base file)

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'localhost'),6379],
        },
    },
}
```

`routing.py` (located on the same level as `settings.py`)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator, OriginValidator

from chat.consumers import ChatConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    # below is our websocket URL
                    url(r"^messages/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)", ChatConsumer),
                ]
            )
        )
    )
})
```

`base.py`

I'm happy to include `consumers.py` and `base.py` if it is relevant.

Comment: hi did you try `pip install channel_redis`?

Comment: Hi friend, I did `pip install channels=2.1.2` and `brew install redis` but will try the above.

Comment: When I try `pip install channels_redis` I get  `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement channel_redis (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for channel_redis`

Comment: I did `pip install channels_redis` and that seemed to install. But I will check now if it solves the issue

Comment: sorry for the typo!

Comment: It's okay, when I install using that command it changes from `channels 2.1.2` and I have written all the code for that version. Then I get a whole bunch of new errors.

Comment: When I try to reinstall using `pip install channels==2.1.2` I get this message `daphne 2.3.0 has requirement asgiref~=3.0, but you'll have asgiref 2.3.2 which is incompatible.`

Comment: i see, try to change the  `"BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer"`

Comment: Now I am getting another problem since I reinstalled channels `from asgiref.compatibility import is_double_callable
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asgiref.compatibility'`

Comment: Okay, I fixed that doing `pip install channels daphne==2.2.5` and will try changing backend now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192363/discussion-between-bear-brown-and-trilla).